# can´t fill my chart using data set

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm having a problem passing the data I retrive from my database in sql server to be used to fill my graph.
It turns out that the error says that the type of data that I am inserting is not correct:

> Error: Serial data points are not values ​​of type System.Data.DataViewManagerListItemTypeDescriptor

Can you help me create a way to convert this data to fill my graph?

My code:

```
 protected void Chart1_Load18(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string cs1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS1"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(cs1))

        {
            var da = new SqlDataAdapter("USE [DB_SACC] SELECT  [Consumo_Medio_Real]  FROM [dbo].[t_faturas]", con1);

            con1.Open();

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            da.Fill(ds);

            var enumerableTable1 = (ds as System.ComponentModel.IListSource).GetList();

            Chart1.Series["Consumo Médio Real"].Points.DataBind(enumerableTable1, "Consumo_Medio_Real", "", "");

            ds.Clear();

            con1.Close();
```

My connection:

```
<connectionStrings>

<add name="CS1" connectionString="Data Source=ASUS;Initial Catalog=DB_SACC;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=1234"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: what exact error do you get? Posting a re-wording which only vaguely resembles the original message is not all that informative. Post the exact message and the line on which it occurs.

Comment: Error: Serial data points are not values ​​of type System.Data.DataViewManagerListItemTypeDescriptor